# Questions about "'duplicate of' navigation only leading in a circle"

Tags: discussion

I was just reviewing in the close votes section of /review when I came across a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/742712) that I believed was correctly marked as a duplicate by previous reviewers. However, when I tried to vote to close it as a duplicate, I received:

> This closure would result in the 'duplicate of' navigation only
>   leading in a circle

(lets called the linked post "post A".) Post A already has 3 close votes marking it as a duplicate of post B, which has already been closed as a duplicate of post A. Now I was unable to complete process of submitting the close vote (because of the error of course) but I have a couple of questions about this:

1. How should this be handled? When something like this happens, should
   the posts be merged?
2. Were the previous 3 close votes on post A allowed because they occurred before post B was closed as a duplicate of A? (This seems pretty obvious, but I just want to know for my own selfish reasons!)

I tried looking into this error, but it turns out that this message is hilariously under-discussed. [Google results](https://www.google.com/#q=%22this+closure+would+result+in+the+%27duplicate+of%27+navigation+only+leading+in+a+circle%22&hl=en&prmd=imvns&filter=0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=2e34b88613e4b1c6&biw=1379&bih=784)

Comment: Does it actually still have that terrible error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I'm responsible for this particular example.

Here's the situation:

The first close-vote brought my attention to the older question. However, when I looked at the [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1658186/922184), it was clearly of "lower quality" than the [newer one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12692111/922184).

1. The newer question had a better title that is more searchable.
2. The newer question was very straight to the point with the question.

So I brought this up in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692111/why-is-such-complex-code-emitted-for-dividing-a-signed-integer-by-a-power-of-two#comment17135413_12692111):

> That does appear to be a dupe. But this one has a better title and is
>   more straight to the point. I'm not sure what the policy is for
>   closing a higher quality question as a dupe of a lower quality one.

And with that, FredOverflow [responded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692111/why-is-such-complex-code-emitted-for-dividing-a-signed-integer-by-a-power-of-two#comment17135459_12692111):

> Well, we could also vote to close the old question as a dupe of the
>   new one...

And that's exactly what happened. But before the older question was closed, the newer question already picked up 3 close votes.

---

1. To answer your question about what to do, just select "Do Not Close". Since, at this point, it really shouldn't be closed anyway.
2. And yes, all 3 close votes are dupe votes for the older question.

Answer (score 0):

I think these close votes should not come up in the review queue. If question A is in the review queue only because it has a close vote as duplicate of question B, but B is closed, then just remove it from the review queue.